# Unhide the hidden module in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, c

I coded a LKM which has a functionality of hiding itself from procfs and sysfs. The problem is when I try to unhide it I get the following error :`libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1882 kmod_module_get_holders: could not open '/sys/module/my_module/holders': No such file or directory`. After this I can see the module is shown in the `lsmod` but with the -2 as the parent PID. When i try to remove the module I get the error saying `ERROR: Module my_module is builtin.`. Here is the code:

```
//HIDE
void hide(void) {
    if(module_hidden) //is hidden
            return;
    module_prev = THIS_MODULE->list.prev;
    list_del_init(&THIS_MODULE->list);                      //procfs view   

    kobject_prev = &THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj;
    kobject_parent_prev = THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj.parent;
    kobject_list_prev = THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj.entry.prev;

    kobject_del(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj);                  //sysfs view
    //list_del(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj.entry);
    module_hidden = (unsigned int)0x1;
}


//SHOW
void unhide(void) {
    if(!module_hidden) //is not hidden
            return;
    list_add(&THIS_MODULE->list, module_prev);              //procfs view

    //list_add(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj.entry, kobject_list_prev);
    kobject_add(kobject_prev, kobject_parent_prev, "my_module");//sysfs view
    module_hidden = (unsigned int)0x0;
}
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your *unhide* functions isn't fully restore the module, when looking at *[kobject_del](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.11/source/lib/kobject.c#L565)* code, we can see that it calls *sysfs_remove_dir* which remove all the sub-directories and files.

When looking at *[kobject_add](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.11/source/lib/kobject.c#L390)* we eventually call *kobject_add_internal*->*create_dir*->*[populate_dir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.11/source/lib/kobject.c#L47)*, which only create files for his ktype default attribute, but as can be seen at *[module_ktype](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.11/source/kernel/params.c#L935)* is NULL,
meaning no files are restored on the call.

So you need to manually restore all his sub-dirs and files, such as refcnt, holders dir, notes dir, sect dir and all his other attributes under *&THIS_MODULE->modinfo_attrs*(when restoring them don't forget to decrease reference count from the module kobject for notes, holders and drivers).

The best thing to do, is understanding the workflow of *mod_sysfs_setup*, for more details of what should be restored.